# How to retrieve data from related past records

Tags: filemaker

I am using Filemaker Pro 12. I want to create a student report that contains results from previous terms. For example, each year there are 4 terms. The report in term 1 contains only the result of term 1. But in term 2, the report contains the results from both term 1 and term 2. This continues until term 4 (end of year) which the report will contain the results from term 1 to term 4.

I created 4 fields `ca1_percent`, `sa1_percent`, `ca2_percent` and `sa2_percent` in the `Results` table. My `Results` table contains all the records of the past results. My relationship graph is shown in the diagram below:

[image]

My problem is that I kept obtaining the records (`mark_percent`) from CA1 only. My fields calculation is shown in the diagram below:

[image]

Can anyone help me?

Update:
The result I obtained from above is shown in the picture below. I have populated upto term 3 results.

[image]

Comment: Are you getting anything out of your SA1_Results_Match relationship, or everything comes out blank?

Comment: I got `ca1_percent` marks in `sa1_percent` field. And only records from SA1 are filled by the values. The records from CA1 are blanks.

Answer (score 1):

Just a thought - might an ExecuteSQL() query to fetch the related ids as a value list, then plonking them into a id-1, id-2, id-3 be more flexible?

Comment: You are right. My solution leads me to this new problem that I asked in this post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16852240/pushing-term-1-results-into-term-3-fields-for-new-students-joining-mid-year. I am looking at using ExecuteSQL solution

Comment: Can you share a little more details? I did a query by `ExecuteSQL("SELECT mark_percent FROM Results WHERE '_kf_studentID' = ?; ""; ""; '_kf_studentID'")`. However I do not get the expected results.

Comment: It could be down to the sort on the relationship itself. I will look at the other question, see if it more light is shed there.

Comment: Standstill - if you have more info, let me know.

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem myself.

Since Filemaker just take the first matched record by default, what I did is to use `GetNthRecord(SA1_Results_Match::mark_percent,2)` to get the marks for SA1, using 3 to get the marks for CA2 and 4 for SA2.

My TO only need be matched by `overall_percent_match` which is a calculated field using `year & " " & subject & " " & _kf_studentID`.