# Pushing term 1 results into term 3 fields for new students joining mid-year

Tags: database, filemaker

I have a table that contains test marks from different terms, `ca1_percent`, `sa1_percent`, `ca2_percent` and `sa2_percent`. These 4 fields reside in the `Results` table that contains results from the different terms.

I used a self-relationship linking using the matched field `overall_percent_match` which is calculated using `year & " " & subject & " " & _kf_studentID`. This relationship allows me to obtain the test results from past terms (of a year). For example, my term 3 results will contain results from term 1 and term 2 (of each subject). All works fine unless there is a new student who joins mid way of the year. If he joins in term 3, his ca2 results (done in term 3) will fall into his `ca1_percent` column (which is supposed to contain term 1 results) like other records before him.

Image shows what I mean.

[image]

I could not figure out the solution. Can anyone help me?

This [StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16775575/how-to-retrieve-data-from-related-past-records) link contains more details of my work that was done related to this problem.

Answer (score 0):

The underlying problem, [per your prior query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16775575/how-to-retrieve-data-from-related-past-records),  is that you're pulling the values through:

```
GetNthRecord(SA1_Results_Match::mark_percent,2)
```

This statement assumes the existence of an N=1, N=2 and N=3. To make this work properly you could do any of the following:

1. Ensure that your Results table always has records from the prior semester, even if the student joins later in the semester. You could keep using GetNthRecord this way, but you will always need to ensure that the records are in order.
2. Use an ExecuteSQL statement to gather only the correct semester's results for the correct summary field.
3. Make four separate relationships, with separate Table Occurrences, to define ca1, sa1, ca2 and sa2 each separately. This looks like what you started out trying to do in the prior question.

Comment: I tried this ExecuteSQL statement but it doesn't work. `ExecuteSQL (
" SELECT __kp_resultID 
FROM Results
WHERE Results_Match_Overall::year = Results::year
AND Results_Match_Overall::_kf_studentID = Results:studentID "; ""; ""
)` I still could not figure the idea to retrieve the record from one row and put it to the field of another.

Comment: Obviously I can't test this statement myself, but I think you want something more like `ExecuteSQL ( " SELECT ca1_percent FROM Results where year = ? AND _kf_studentID = ?" ; "" ; "" ; Results::year ; Results:studentID )`

Comment: It returns a ?. I tried `ExecuteSQL ( " SELECT ca1_percent 
FROM Results where year = ? 
AND _kf_studentID = ? 
AND assessment_type = 'CA1' "
; "" ; "" ; 
Results::year ; Results::_kf_studentID; mark_percent )` because `mark_percent` is the field that holds the result for that particular term, and I included `CA1` because this field contains only the CA1 results, even for records that are in other terms. My try also returns ?. Still figuring it. I'm not familiar with SQL.

Comment: I recommend really dissecting the ExecuteSQL statement to see which part isn't working right. Start with just "SELECT CA1_percent FROM Results" and see if that works. Also, it looks like _kf_studentID may need to be quoted specially because of the leading underscore: http://fmforums.com/forum/topic/83282-executesql/

Comment: Seems like too difficult for me to solve in the short time available using ExecuteSQL(). If I were to use TO for 4 separate relationships, I get back to the problem in my prior question. I somehow suspect my relationship should  be matched by `overall_percent_match` and `_kf_year_termID`. However, I get back the the same result in my prior post, which is the `ca1_percent` values populating the `sa1_percent` and `ca2_percent` fields when I used calculation `CA1_Result_Match_Overall::mark_percent`. Can you suggest whether my TO relationships are correct?